# Shiny output and R MarkDown render_site()

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny, r-markdown

I'm facing an issue regarding the use of Shiny outputs in a R MarkDown document when trying to export a two-paged site through the use of render_site() (rmarkdown package)

Here's the chunk of code that create my issue (located within a knitr or one of the .Rmd documents):

```
uiOutput("main")

output$main <- renderUI({
  if(test$n != 0){
    plotOutput("mainPlot", height = test$n*length(input$yAxes)*400)
  }
})

output$mainPlot <- renderPlot({do.call("grid.arrange", c(test$plots, ncol = 1))})
```

**When processing, render_site() tells me that the "output" object is not defined.** Running the .Rmd file alone works fine; the issue only appears when trying to include it as a website. 
Finally, the website is successfully created when I remove the lines above.

**Are output$foo not supported by R MarkDown** or am I missing something dumb?

Thank you very much in advance,

Regards,
Paul

---

PS: I obviously searched before asking, I've been trying to figure this out for hours now ._.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the output-generating code into a function?

```
server <- function (input, output) {
    output$main <- renderUI({
    if(test$n != 0){
    plotOutput("mainPlot", height = test$n*length(input$yAxes)*400)
    }
   })

    output$mainPlot <- renderPlot({do.call("grid.arrange", c(test$plots, ncol = 1))})
}
```